# Using AJAX to check for changes and make updates only if change has occurred

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web

Currently I've made a poll on a website I'm working on. The poll has to be changed/reset a lot, as well as embedded across multiple pages. There's an admin interface which allows the admin to change the poll topic and questions. Now, when the admin changes the poll questions a file on the server gets changed from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 like this:

```
$filename = "check";
$content = file_get_contents($filename, true);

if($content == 1) { $content = 0; }


else{ $content = 1; }



file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

The pages that have the poll embedded then uses ajax to check this file for changes every 5 seconds, and if the check file has been changed from its initial value, it updates the poll with the getpoll function.

```
function getPoll()
{
 $('#pollo').show();
 document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML="<img src='ajax-loader.gif'></img>";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    if(document.getElementById("pollcheck").innerHTML=="")
    {
        $('#pollo').hide();
    }
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/poll/index2.html",true);
xmlhttp.send(null);

}

function checkpoll()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
      xml=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
else
      {
      xml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
xml.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xml.readyState==4 && xml.status==200)
        {
        check = xml.responseText;
        }
      }
xml.open("GET","../poll/check",true);
xml.send(null);
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 
//upon loading the page, get the current poll, and set the initial value of check and        pcheck
    getPoll();
    checkpoll();
    pcheck = check;
}


setInterval(function(){
//check the check page every 5 seconds, if check isn't set, set it, if check isn't equal to pcheck, grab the new poll
try{
    checkpoll();
    if(check == "")
    {
        checkpoll();
    }

    if(check != pcheck)
    {
        getPoll();
    pcheck = check;
    }
}

catch(Exception){
    alert("ERROR, try refreshing");
}

},5000)
```

Now this seems to work fairly well, but I know there has to be a better method to check for changes across a server then with xml request calls every x amount of seconds. Also, if the xml request fails, sometimes it can break the updater all together. http://lodeclaw.ardentforge.net/ This is the website the poll is currently running on.

Comment: why not just use a timestamp check?  On load of the file containing the poll details, store the timestamp, then compare that timestamp to the one on the server to see if the file is newer.  you could have an ajax call that simply returns a timestamp for comparison, and another for fetching the new file only if it has changed.                                                             Also, I don't know your overall design needs, but checking if a poll changed every 5 seconds seems pretty fast, by the time I read the poll it could technically change before I can vote.

Comment: That last point you made is why I have a bit of an issue with my current method of checking the poll. Essentially, the poll doesn't even need to be there most of the time, and is generally set to hide. But when it's time to bring the poll up, it's got to change quickly, probably no more then 10-15 seconds, then close itself fairly quickl. Which is why I asked if there was some other way of checking to see if the file had changed. Because the poll needs to update almost as soon as it's changed, but because of that I'm left making ajax calls all the time when they may not even be necessary.

Comment: The poll is basically used to determine a winner at the end of every round of a game, among other things. So if too much time passes between when the poll is changed, and when the round has ended, it just slows everything down.